# how to recognize mobile application javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wanted to hide header only in mobile applications, but have to show header in all mobile browsers as same as in desktop browsers. how can i recognize mobile application through css media queries or in java script or else is there any choice to find mobile application??
can you please help me i can i hide html header only on mobile applications ??
i have tried below java script code but i did not get result

```js
    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
    var isMobile = {
        Android: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function () {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);
        },
        any: function () {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };
    var mobOpera = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1;
    var mobChrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1;
    var mobSafari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1;
    var mobFirefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1;
    var mobIe = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true);
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 &&     nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));

if (isOpera || isFirefox || isSafari || isIE || isEdge || isChrome || isBlink) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("display", "block");
    }

    else if (mobOpera || mobChrome || mobSafari || mobFirefox || mobIe) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("display", "block");
    }
    else if(is_android || isMobile.any()){
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("display", "block");
    }
    else
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: i think for mobile application you have created app so in app code hide the header.

Comment: @Leothelion in which app code have to hide header??

Comment: @Leothelion is there any choice to hide header in mobile application with css or javascript ...?

Comment: according to me, if you are talking about mobile app then sure it is built in ios or android then code for that is not related to web code for site. In code of mobile app..hide them, if  you don't want to show..

Comment: @Leothelion means have to write code in android application development code?? is there any possibility to hide header from css or javascript ??

Comment: I don't think we can do it with css as css can't check that its open in mobile or web..not much knowledge of js so sorry..